# Ncss Type Count violation

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm not really clear with this violation raised by PMD. Basically I have 2 questions:

1. What should I do to get rid of this violation?
2. What does the following statement mean?

> The type has an NCSS line count of 944    Parameters
>   minimum:      The type NCSS count reporting threshold: Default is 1500.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[PMD Code size rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/codesize.html).

NCSS stands for Non-Commented Source Code lines.  Methods and/or classes that have high NCSS counts are (at a very high level) too long, and can probably be split up. High numbers of NCSS are bad.

Additionally, it sounds like you might be using Sonar version 2.10 or prior, as [Sonar Bug 2676](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2676) was fixed in 2.11.

Comment: Have read the Sonar Bug 2676. So you mean that my class size (without comment) is 944 lines and more than default 800 lines thus giving error?

Comment: That seems to be the way that I'm reading the message, yes.  Your file is 944 lines of source code (ignoring comments and whitespace), and the default setting is 800.  Note that (from how I read it) lines that only contain braces count as SLOC.

Comment: Funny, it like to find this defect on autogenerated HashCode and Equals methods. Should be a way to ignore it as there is no reason to put comments in those.

Comment: default valve of pmd 4.3 is 1500 (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/rules/codesize.html). I use sonar 3.5.1 and still reports this, Then it must still use older version of pmd.

Comment: This NCSS is often crappy: IntelliJ generates equals and hashCode lines and classes with let's say 15 fields, which to my opinion is doable, generate these Sonar comments.